# HTML5 Presentation – Adding a Fade Transition Between Slides

Tags: html, presentation

I have a school assignment to create a presentation in HTML5 and found a template that’s helping through this assignment. Its not complete, below is the working template, I would like to add a fade transition between slides to this presentation, and I can not figure out the javascript to add the fade transition. Here’s the link to the working presentation and I’m hoping to get some help.

http://perlaparra.com/uopx/sandbox/987153624/#intro

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the code you have? You could try using JQuery effects like this:

```
<div id="clickme">
Click here
</div>
    <img id="book" src="book.png" alt="" width="100" height="123">

    // With the element initially hidden, we can show it slowly:
    $( "#clickme" ).click(function() {
    $( "#book" ).fadeIn( "slow", function() {
    // Animation complete
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your link you don't have to use JS fading libraries
You can handle it using CSS3 
Just add these 2 lines into your CSS

```
.slide {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```